# How to use the parameter from POST body for GET route

Tags: java, rest-assured

Hey I am new to rest assured managed to get the POST route Test case working the response body for below test case is

```
public void submissionsUserPostTest() {

    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("username", "XYZ");

    String jsonString = data.toJSONString();

    Response request = given().contentType("application/json")
            .body(jsonString).expect().statusCode(201).when()
            .post(postRoute);

    request.print();
}
```

Body

```
{"createdAt":"2014-04-16T20:04:40.560Z","updatedAt":"2014-04-16T20:04:40.560Z","id":"51de8ae0-","_links":{"self":{"href":"/assignments/51de8ae0-c43e-44c3-b46d-f48a25739385"}},"username":"XYZ","uploadDate":"2014-04-16T20:04:40.560Z"}
```

So my question is
How can I use the id which is generated by POST route into my GET route /assignments/{id} using request??

Comment: I don't understand. What is `postRoute`?

Comment: postRoute is a string which contains "http://some address/assignments"

Comment: And what are you trying to retrieve? A value from the JSON?

Comment: Yes i should had mentioned it

Comment: You can edit your question to add more details. Have you looked into any JSON parsers?

Comment: I will look into JSON parser,I have just stared looking into rest assured today can you please give me reference like how to remove the id param from the POST response body

Comment: Start by looking into the [json format](http://www.json.org/). Understand what a JSON object is and how they can be nested. Then choose a JSON parser. Options include Jackson, Gson, json-simple. org.json, and others. Read the body of the response, parse it with the library chosen and use the corresponding API to extract the value you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
String id = response.jsonPath().getString("id");
```

then pass the stored value [i.e. id] to your GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the self link? In that case you can do:

```
String assignment = 
given().
        contentType("application/json").
        body(jsonString)
when().
        post(postRoute).
then().
        statusCode(201).
extract().
      path("_links.self.href");

when().
       get(assignment).
then().
       ...
```